# Messy REST annotations

Tags: java, rest, annotations, resteasy, swagger

In my project we create REST interfaces using [RestEasy](http://resteasy.jboss.org/) and use [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) to document them. The problem is that this requires many annotations, and might look like the following:

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Create a person object",
        notes = "Create a person object" +
                "Return the newley created person object",
        response = Person.class)
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, message = "Internal server error"),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_PRECONDITION_FAILED, message = "Precondition failed"),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, message = "Bad request"),
        @ApiResponse(code = HttpStatus.SC_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, message = "Unprocessable entity")
})
@POST
@Path("rest/v1/persons")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
Person createPerson(
        @HeaderParam("SecurityToken") String token,
        @ApiParam(value = "person", defaultValue = "{ \"name\": = \"Bart Simpson\", \"age\": = 9 }") Person person);
```

Most of the annotations look more or less the same in all our methods. So we copy and paste a lot, and all of these annotations make our interfaces quite unreadable and it is hard to tell exactly what the methods are doing.

So I'm wondering if anyone has an idea on how we could have the same functionality but to somehow hide all of those annotations, or at least some of them.

Comment: I don't know Swagger but maybe it supports stereotypes. That way you might be able to reduce all those @ApiXxx annotations to one.

Comment: I assume the main issue is with @ApiResponses?

Comment: Does Swagger support meta-annotations? That's the usual Spring approach.

Comment: I found [Swagger issue 690](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/690) so I'm guessing they are still considering how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Create custom annotations and annotate them with jaxrs and swagger annotations. Spring’s [RestController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.java) is a good example:

```
@Controller
@ResponseBody
public @interface RestController {

}
```

Edit: If meta-annotations is not supported by Swagger and/or RestEasy, you can always try [APT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/apt/GettingStarted.html) as a solution.